# Workaround to import users as site-members on wix.com

Tags: velo

Does anyone know if there is a way to get around the limitation on wix.com to manually change a contact's status to "site member"? Or instead, not manually setting one by one, but to import hundreds of users from one website where they paid to be a member, but that website (bigtent) is shutting down, so I am trying to get those paid members to be "site members" on my wix site. Any suggestions or ideas? Thanks

UPDATE:

I finally did it, but it was not simple or by "import". I set site members to auto-approval, used wix code to create an array of the people's info (first name, last name, email address, a default password I created, and some custom fields I had to create to get around the limitation of writing to the CRM fields for address). I then looped through the array and used:

```
wixUsers.register(email, password, {
    contactInfo: {
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName,
    "HouseStreet": address,
    "HouseCity": city,
    "HouseState": state,
    "HouseZip": zip,
 //   "Phones": [phone],
    "labels":["online registration (wix)"]
            }
        })
```

Then I emailed all the people and told them to go to the site and click on forgot password to create their own password, but at least their account was created and info already there. 
Now the problem is getting their paid membership into the paid plans with an expiration date.

**Is it possible to write or add to the array from getPricingPlans?** 
I'm trying this, but it's not working (no error message but it doesn't change the date when I look from the dashboard):

```
 wixUsers.currentUser.getPricingPlans()
    .then((planList) => {
            let lastActiveRecord = planList[0];
            let expirationDate = Date.parse(lastActiveRecord.expiryDate);
            let textPlan = `<span>Plan Name: ${lastActiveRecord.name} and expiration date: ${expirationDate}</span>`;
            $w("#textPlan").html = textPlan; //so I can see it on the screen
          planList[0].expiryDate = new Date(2019, 6, 1);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you set up so that all members on your site will be auto approved and then import them that should happen.

If not you must make some Wix Code to read in a CSV file and set the imported members to site member using code. You can create new users using wixUsers library in code and createUser and there set anything you want on each user.

Then they will be Site Members for sure, I have done it several time.